# Cypress Intercept (Data Mocking) bad practice for functionality testing?

Tags: cypress

New here in stack overflow and recently we have been introduced to cypress. We are an automation team that currently uses selenium chrome driver for our test. We are trying to utilize cypress by migrating some of the long running test that we have. But the issue is it will be implemented on the build process when developers push a code (So more of a unit test with no actual automation environment. Just raw code and you will need to mock all your test data). I'm skeptic on the way we can just "Intercept" some of the routes and tell us to return certain object by "Mocking" via json fixtures. I think if we do this we are missing out a lot of the things that is covered by our actual automation test. Like "Verification of the element properties" since mocking will always present you the element that you need. Loading time of the element and possible stability issue which you can't "Cheat" on an actual automation run happening on an actual automation environment with it's test data.

I feel like our old setup covers more testing functionality wise and give us a closer glimpse on how our user actually interacts with our Site. For cypress master could you give me advise on my concern?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1):

In my team we had the same discussion. It depends on what you want to test. If you just want to check that your Front-end code runs properly and does what it is expected to do with a given response, you should mock the responses. In this way you can also provide a wrong response and check that your Front-end shows the corresponding error, for instance.
But we have decided not to mock responses because like this we can detect not only Front-end issues, but also the Back-end ones so we are able to warn their team, even if it is not our "fault".

Comment: Thank you very much for that input. Glad to know that we are not the only one skeptic with the all this mocking and intercepts.

Answer (score 0):

If I can add my experience, we decided to mock our answers to test only the Front-End part of the application. In our case we already have functional tests on the Back side, and we also have the problem of the database, to test data insertions that can't be duplicated, we would need a system to reset the database after each test run.
If I can add my experience, we decided to mock our answers to test only the Front-End part of the application. In our case we already have functional tests on the Back side, and we also have the problem of the database, to test data insertions that can't be duplicated, we would need a system to reset the database after each test run.